# Common-Js and Material-UI Icons. Understanding why Icon won't load. (React Js)

Tags: reactjs, commonjs, material-ui

I'm attempting to run the following code:

```
"use strict";

var React = require('react');
var Router = require('react-router');
var Link = Router.Link;

var Material = require('material-ui');
var ThemeManager = new Material.Styles.ThemeManager();
var Colors = Material.Styles.Colors;
var dropdown = Material.Icons.NavigationArrowDropDown; //This icon cannot be found

var Home = React.createClass({
    childContextTypes: {
        muiTheme: React.PropTypes.object
    },

    getChildContext: function () {
        return {
            muiTheme: ThemeManager.getCurrentTheme()
        };
    },

    componentWillMount: function () {
        ThemeManager.setPalette({
            accent1Color: Colors.cyan500
        });
    },

    render: function () {
        return (
            <div>
                <Material.AppBar title="Test" showMenuIconButton={false}>
                </Material.AppBar>
                <Material.List>
                    <Material.ListItem primaryText={"Queue"} leftIcon={<Material.Icons.NavigationChevronLeft/>} />
                    <Material.ListItem primaryText={"Log"} leftIcon={<Material.Icons.NavigationArrowDropDown/>} />
                    <Material.ListItem primaryText={"Settings"} />
                </Material.List>
                <Material.Paper>
                    <span>This is some text</span>
                    <Material.RaisedButton label="Super Secret Password" primary={true}/>
                </Material.Paper>
            </div>
        );
    }
});

module.exports = Home;
```

I've included the necessary packages and the code runs fine if I don't include

> Material.Icons.NavigationArrowDropDown;

I've navigated to material-ui (0.11.1) and the file does exist there as an export in the following path:

lib > svg-icons > Navigation > Arrow_drop_down.js and the source code is as follows:

```
'use strict';

var React = require('react/addons');
var PureRenderMixin = React.addons.PureRenderMixin;
var SvgIcon = require('../../svg-icon');

var NavigationArrowDropDown = React.createClass({
  displayName: 'NavigationArrowDropDown',

  mixins: [PureRenderMixin],

  render: function render() {
    return React.createElement(
      SvgIcon,
      this.props,
      React.createElement('path', { d: 'M7 10l5 5 5-5z' })
    );
  }

});

module.exports = NavigationArrowDropDown;
```

However, when compiling and running the application it cannot find the item and complains it does not exist, yet the other item

> Material.Icons.NavigationChevronLeft

Gets found without issue. This file (with the exclusion of my router and app.js) are my entire project.

Since both files exist in the same folder, I cannot understand why the one reference is found and the other isn't?

The error occurs at runtime and jsLint doesnt pick it up. Additionally, when removing the listItem icon my page renders correctly. The problem appears to be tied directly to this component.

Additional Note: I have removed the var dropdown, it was there merely to demonstrate how the export is not being found from Material UI.

tl;dr : Material UI Icon class in the same folder as another Icon class is not being picked up. Why?

Comment: Are you using browserify?

Comment: Yes I am using gulp and browserify. I'll zip up my source code for those interested

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BzdvbWk2AAe2TkRINlVzSURtRzQ/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can see in [src/index.js](https://github.com/callemall/material-ui/blob/master/src/index.js#L45-L49), `NavigationArrowDropDown` isn't being set on `Material.Icons`, while `NavigationChevronLeft` is. The component is used in [other](https://github.com/callemall/material-ui/blob/5c6f1c631f1da7e5c8972d275a2ccf08544df3ee/src/drop-down-menu.jsx) [places](https://github.com/callemall/material-ui/blob/5c6f1c631f1da7e5c8972d275a2ccf08544df3ee/src/lists/list-item.jsx), but is never publicly exposed through `material-ui`'s main export.

However, you can still require it like you would any other file:

```js
var NavigationArrowDropDown = require('material-ui/lib/svg-icons/navigation/arrow-drop-down');
```

Looking at the [README](https://github.com/callemall/material-ui/blob/master/README.md#usage), it looks like this is the recommended way to reach single components.